# Android: how to avoid ViewRootImpl: cancle motionEvent because of threeGesture detecting on Xiaomi devices

Tags: android, touch, gesture, xiaomi

When I press with 3 fingers at once, on my 1+ phone with Oxygen OS everything works fine, but on Xiaomi devices I get this:

`ViewRootImpl: cancle motionEvent because of threeGesture detecting`

I didn't find much about this problem, but tried this:

```
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return true
    }
```

But it doesn't work. If I disable 3 fingers to take a screenshot gesture in the system settings, everything works fine. Can I do something so that I don't have to disable 3 finger screenshot, but still get my 3 separate finger presses instead of that error?

Comment: The system is on top of any app. It receives all gestures first and provides them to the app until it decides that it should handle them on its own. As the app, you can only handle this cancelation and show alert to the user with some instructions on why the system probably intercepts this event and how to turn them off. Not sure you can do anything like ask the system to not doing this.

Comment: @RevakoOA that's what I thought. Thanks